# How to blur background in Adobe Premiere like meeting apps like Zoom or Google Meet?

Tags: premiere, adobe

Meeting software such as Zoom or Google Meet allow someone to blur their background while allowing the face and body of the person to be shown clearly during the video conference. I would like to record some presentation of mine without a green screen first and then I want to blur my background using adobe premiere pro? I do not want to blur the background while I am recording. I want to blur my background after the recording. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is any way to do this easily in Premiere.

You can blur out certain portions of the image using a Gaussian blur effect, then mask around your subject, but you need to be careful that your subject doesn’t intrude on the mask, and it may look unnatural anyway.

The best solution I have found to this is by using After Effects. I make a foreground layer by duplicating the footage layer, then running a Roto Brush effect across the footage to isolate the foreground. Then I can blur or adjust the background layer. This is time consuming and requires a fair amount of manual adjustment (although a lot less than RotoBrush version 1 did).

**Update:**
Thinking about it - it might be possible to output your video as a stream from [OBS](https://obsproject.com/), then choose this as a source in Google Meet or Zoom, set background to blur, then record the output from Meet/Zoom.  I haven't tried this approach.

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of any other software that might be able to do this, such as Final cut pro or Sony Vegas?

Comment: I'm not - I think the foreground-detection algorithms are quite complicated and the web conferencing companies view them as proprietary tools that they don't share.  It would be very useful if there was one available.  Runway might be able to do it, but I haven't used it. https://runwayml.com/green-screen/

Comment: As tomh points out above, I tried his suggestion to stream the video from OBS that exposes a virtual camera which I can open in Zoom, Meet, etc. 
Zoom then applies the background effect quite competently to the existing video ! :-)
The only issue is that I haven't found a way to get the audio through to Zoom. Any ideas why?

Comment: I can only speak for MacOS, but passing audio between applications is fiddly. You may need to use Audio Hijack, or try Soundflower for a free way to do this.

Comment: As tomh points out above, I tried to stream the video from OBS which exposes a virtual camera which I can open in Zoom, Meet, etc. Zoom then applies the background effect quite competently! :-)
The only issue is that I haven't found a way to get the audio through to Zoom

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly easily in DaVinci Resolve - even the freeware version.

Essentially, you select an area to to remain clean at the start of your clip, set it to be motion-tracked [DaVinci makes tracking moving objects very easy], then blur its inverse.

There's a 2-minute YouTube guide on how it works. I can't find anything simpler in text.